# ColdFusion - Taking a string and breaking it down into individual variables

Tags: string, variables, coldfusion

I am receiving a string from another application that contains various pieces of information. The items are always in the same order, but the length of variable information can change. Each item is separated by an underscore and prefixed by a letter and colon.

**Example:**

*A:12345678_B:5482945_C:20220911_D:20230402_E:3.94*

Ideally, I want to break it down so that (in Coldfusion) I can end up with a series of variable that I would set as the values of A,B,C,D and E above.

Does anyone know any easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at anything? Maybe start with the basics? https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-by-category/list-functions.html

Comment: I'd use list functions for this.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Seems like a reasonable question to me. Only thing though, Martin: it's usually good to let us know what you've tried before having to ask the question.

Comment: Apologies for not explain what I'd tried (or not in this case). My CF skills are somewhat limited and mainly relate to reading/writing to databases, so I hadn't actually tried anything because I didn't know what to do. I will try the suggestions made and report back. Thanks!!!

Comment: No worries mate. We were all there at some stage. Lemme know if you can't get yer brain around that code.

Answer (score 6):

I think @Will is missing one small part of your requirement, which is

> I can end up with **a series of variable[s]** that I would set as the values of A,B,C,D and E above"

To me this demonstrates more what you want to achieve:

```
raw = "A:12345678_B:5482945_C:20220911_D:20230402_E:3.94"

asArray = raw.listToArray("_")
asStruct = asArray.reduce((struct, kvAsString) => {
    var key = kvAsString.listFirst(":")
    var value = kvAsString.listRest(":")
    struct[key] = value
    return struct
}, {})

writeDump(asStruct)
```

(runnable @ trycf.com: https://trycf.com/gist/e84aea475957e27b5dea2643e7c207ad/acf2021?theme=monokai)

[image: dump showing results of code]

Whilst this does not create "a series of variables" it does separate out the key from the value, and from there you can append that to whatever scope you need the variables in (eg: `variables.append(asStruct)`)

---

In future please:

1. show us what you've already tried
2. give us the full intended result, don't just describe it.

Basically: always include code when you ask questions.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I did try this and got it to work also. Do you know if this will work on Lucee as well?

Comment: You can change the engine on that trycf.com link I gave you, and see for yourself (and the answer is "yes").

Comment: I've hit a strange issue. Adam's code was working fine on my CF2021 test server. However, I've put it on my live CF2016 server (yes, I know that's no longer supported, but I cannot get it upgraded yet), and ColdFusion errors out:  

Invalid construct.  
A script statement must end with ";".  
The CFML compiler was processing:  
  
A script statement beginning with raw on line 101, column 9.  
A cfscript tag beginning on line 100, column 10.  
A cfscript tag beginning on line 100, column 10.  
A cfscript tag beginning on line 100, column 10.  

How do I get it working on CF2016?

Comment: The error message... um... *tells you* what the problem is. What do you think this might mean: `A script statement must end with ";".`?

Comment: I did try adding ; in at what I believed to be appropriate places. It then threw an error on the comma. As I don’t know cfscript well I hit a wall after that.

Comment: This version runs on CF2016: https://trycf.com/gist/4e58fc1a5455ab51885753449eee91ab/acf2016?theme=monokai. Arrow functions weren't added to CFML until CF2018 I think. It's always important to mention the version of [whatever you are using] in your question, if it's not the current version. Even then: best to mention it to avoid doubt & time wasting.

Comment: Thank you very much Adam. You are right of course, but I didn't factor the version in as being a potential problem until I tried to run it on the CF2016 server... I know for next time. Thanks again for taking the time to help - you saved me considerable hair loss! :)

Answer (score 0):

Gives you an array of the items.  If you're handy with Regular Expressions, this could be even simpler.  This is Lucee compatible.  Adobe CFML didn't like the var commands outside of a function.

```
<cfscript>
 var aNewItems = [];
 var sString = "A:12345678_B:5482945_C:20220911_D:20230402_E:3.94";
 var aItems = listToArray(sString, "_");
 for( var sLetter in aItems){
    aNewItems.append(listFirst(sLetter, ":"));
 }
 writeDump(aNewItems);
</cfscript>
```

Here's an Adobe CFML version that worked on TryCF.com:

```
<cfscript>
 local.aNewItems = [];
 local.sString = "A:12345678_B:5482945_C:20220911_D:20230402_E:3.94";
 local.aItems = listToArray(local.sString, "_");
 for( local.sLetter in aItems){
    local.aNewItems.append(listFirst(local.sLetter, ":"));
 }
 writeDump(local.aNewItems);
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score -1):

And just for fun, here is a list function answer:

```
<cfset TheString = 'A:12345678_B:5482945_C:20220911_D:20230402_E:3.94'>
<cfoutput>
<cfloop list = #TheString# index = "NameValue" delimiters = "_">
Variable #ListFirst(NameValue, ":")# = #ListLast(NameValue, ":")# <br>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Run code here ==> https://trycf.com/gist/34321917c06643de1d3c25b611243466/acf2021?theme=monokai

Comment: I tried the script that Will listed below, which worked. (Thanks Will!) However,  think I will rework it with this, simply because I want something that will work with both CF and Lucee out of the box.

Forgive my ignorance - how would I reference each individual variable?

Comment: This answer doesn't actually do what you ask. It just displays stuff.